# ¿Por que no se me aplica la resta a una variable?

Tags: java

El monton 1 deberia valer 3

Resultado por consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Programa

```
package Nim;
import java.util.*;
public class Nim {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private int monton1;
private int monton2;
private int monton3;
public static int elegir;

//CONSTRUCTOR

Nim(){
    monton1 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-3)+3);
    monton2 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-3)+3);
    monton3 = (int) (Math.random()*(6-3)+3);
}

//METODOS GET AND SET

public int getMonton1() {
    return monton1;
}
public void setMonton1(int monton1) {
    this.monton1 = monton1;
}
public int getMonton2() {
    return monton2;
}
public void setMonton2(int monton2) {
    this.monton2 = monton2;
}
public int getMonton3() {
    return monton3;
}
public void setMonton3(int monton3) {
    this.monton3 = monton3;
}

//METODOS

public void elegirMonton() {
    System.out.println("Elegir un monton: ");
    System.out.println("(1) Monton 1 que tiene: " + getMonton1());
    System.out.println("(2) Monton 2 que tiene: " + getMonton2());
    System.out.println("(3) Monton 3 que tiene: " + getMonton3());
    elegir = sc.nextInt();
    if(elegir == 1) {
        elegir = monton1;
    }else if(elegir == 2){
        elegir = monton2;
    }else {
        elegir = monton3;
    }
    comprobarMonton(elegir);
}

public int comprobarMonton(int elegir) {
    if(elegir<=0) {
        System.out.println("Error: ese montón ya no tiene palillos");
        elegirMonton();
    }
    return elegir;
}

public void elegirPalillos(){
    System.out.println("Cuantos paillos quieres retirar, 1 o 2: ");
    int palillos = sc.nextInt();
    comprobarPalillos(palillos);
}

public int comprobarPalillos(int palillos) {
    if(palillos > elegir) {
        System.out.println("Error: ese montón no tiene tantos palillos");
        elegirPalillos();
    }
    return elegir - palillos;
}

public void comprobarFinJuego() {
    do {
        elegirMonton();
        elegirPalillos();
    }while(monton1 + monton2 + monton3 != 0);
}
}
```

Comment: La sentencia `return elegir - palillos;` está siendo ignorada cuando llamas al método `comprobarPallilos(palillos);` en `elegirPalillos()`

Answer (score 1):

Deberías cambiar el método `comprobarPalillos`, podría ser de tipo `void` ya que no importa que valor retornes, solo importa la operación que realizas y a que variable le asignas:

```
public void comprobarPalillos(int palillos) {
    if(palillos > elegir) {
        System.out.println("Error: ese montón no tiene tantos palillos");
        elegirPalillos();
    }
    if (elegir == 1 ){
      monton1 =  monton1- palillos;
    } else  if (elegir == 2 ){
      monton2 =  monton2- palillos;
    } else {
      monton3 =  monton3- palillos;
    }
    //también puedes usar switch en lugar de estos if

    //Codigo que he tenido que cambiar para que me funcione
    if (elegir == monton1 ){
      monton1 =  monton1- palillos;
    } else  if (elegir == monton2 ){
      monton2 =  monton2- palillos;
    } else {
      monton3 =  monton3- palillos;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Entonces cuando realizo la resta (elegir - palillos) ?

Comment: según entiendo, la variable "elegir" es la opción que seleccionas, 1 ,2 o 3,  lo que vas a restar son los palillos que está en tu variable int palillos = sc.nextInt(); ,  que se la pasas al método comprobarPalillos, ahí restas y le asignas el nuevo monto a los montos que corresponden segun la variable elegir.

Comment: Sigue sin realizarme la resta, lo que yo quiero es que al aplicar la resta a la variable elegir, esta se aplique al monton que yo he elegido, es decir si elegir corresponde al monton1, la resta se debe aplicar al monton1

Comment: eso es lo que está escrito en el código :S

Comment: tienes que restar el valor "elegir" why ? el elegir no es solo tu variable de selección ?

Comment: pero si observas la imagen que he subido se puede comprobar como la resta no se aplica al monton seleccionado

Comment: claro que no porque tu código está mal, por eso te puse el código, probaste con mi código ?

Answer (score 0):

Porque nunca lo igualas, tendrías que tener un setter e igualarlo

```
public boolean comprobarPalillos(int palillos) {
    if(palillos > elegir) {
        System.out.println("Error: ese montón no tiene tantos palillos");
        return false
    }
    switch(elegir) {
       case 1: setMonton1(getMonton1() - palillos); break;
       case 2: setMonton2(getMonton2() - palillos); break;
       case 3: setMonton3(getMonton3() - palillos); break;
   }
   return true
}
```

Esta parte verifica el montón elegido y aplica el set al montón. ahora el retun boolean te va a servir porque en caso de ser false deberás ejecutar nuevamente elegir palillos, esto quedaría mejor fuera del método, ya que en caso de quedar adentro cuando acabe la función elegir palillos, regresará a donde se quedo en comprobar palillos

ahora en donde lo mandas a llamar has esto

```
public void elegirPalillos(){
    System.out.println("Cuantos paillos quieres retirar, 1 o 2: ");
    int palillos = sc.nextInt();
    if(!comprobarPalillos(palillos)){
      elegirPalillos();
    }
}
```

Aunque en teoría esto no sería necesario dado que lo estás haciendo en el while, por lo que podría quedar así

```
public void elegirPalillos(){
        System.out.println("Cuantos paillos quieres retirar, 1 o 2: ");
        int palillos = sc.nextInt();
        comprobarPalillos(palillos);

}
```